# Microsoft Excel Consolidate 2 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am really not sure what is my proper keyword to the the question Title and also what to search as i rarely use excel.

However i have these 2 different Columns as per picture below :

[image]

I believe if i shown you expected result would be more helpful.

Result is consolidation of left column into 1 distinct value , while the amount on the right column is summarized based on the total rows per each distinct value. As so :

[image]

I hope i am making sense. Please do guide me on this as i am very basic with Microsoft office's tools.

Comment: It is called a Pivot Table, it is on the Insert tab.

Comment: Ah let me try that. I'll give it a go. Thank you Mr Scott

Comment: Thank you again , pivot answered the question.

I am able to do as per my expected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Answer as per in comment.

It is called a Pivot Table, it is on the Insert tab. - Scott Craner

After playing around the pivot table for 5 to 10 minutes , i am able to achieve the expected result.